# How to modify qemu-kvm bios?

Tags: bios, kvm

I know qemu-kvm use seabios as pc bios.i just want let vm created by qemu-kvm show a custom JPEG image during bootup. How to modify the file bios.bin?

Answer (score 2):

According to this, the BIOS comes from Bochs: Just download Bochs and you can `make` it yourself.

https://forums.mydigitallife.net/threads/modified-bios-for-kvm-qemu-bochs-bios.12401/

Comment: I see the site above, but how to make the Bochs to show a custom JPEG image during boot up? i can not get the answer for my goal.